# global/app lib folders import in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django structure like this (only showing libs):

```
project/lib/ # Global libraries that will be used cross apps
project/lib/global_stuff.py
project/apps/app1/lib/special_for_app1.py
project/apps/app2/lib/special_for_app2.py
```

Some apps don't have a lib folder.

`from apps.app1.lib import special_for_app1` works fine. But how can I import from the global lib folder when I am inside a folder already containing a local lib folder?

From inside the apps views.py file on one of the apps:

---

```
from lib import global_stuff
```

Gives me `ImportError: cannot import name global_stuff`

---

from .lib import global_stuff

Gives me `ImportError: cannot import name global_stuff`

---

```
from ..lib import global_stuff
```

Gives me `ImportError: No module named lib`

---

```
from ...lib import global_stuff
```

Gives me `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

---

```
from project.lib import global_stuff
```

Works, but I really dont want to be stuck with using the project name itself in the import.

---

Is there any way to solve this, not using the project name in the import, or changing the whole lib idea.

Or is there any other good practice to store the main part of the code?

Comment: have you made sure that every directory has a `__init__.py`? Have you put the "/path/to/project" in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Yes, every directory have an __init__.py and the first entry in sys.path is the project directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct for not wanting to associate the project name with the imports, so there is a common pattern for this:

```
project/
  |__/source/
  |     |__/lib/
  |     |__/app/
  |__/deployment/  # code for your production deployment maybe
  |
  |__/docs/   
  |__/tests/
  |__README
  |__requirements.txt
```

and put  /path/to/project inside your paths on your virtualenv(you use virtualenv right?).

Then you can do inside your code

```
from source.lib.blah import foo
from source.app.baz import bar
```

EDIT: This is only optimal if you don't release your code as open source of course. Only when you have an internal project where the management keeps changing the name of the project :D

Comment: Yes, virtualenv and heroku and the structure you pointed out. But instead of called the directory source, I have called it the project name itself. Maybe I should just rename it.

Comment: I hope you read my edit! If you plan to release it on the community you better stick to a project name! Imagine someone having your project as a third party app and doing `from source import blah`. Not good :)

Comment: Yes, I read it, and "luckily" I cant release this as an open-source project. "source" as a name looks a little wrong to me however, but very usable. Let me know if you come up with a better name :)

Comment: I'm the worst person in SO to ask for naming things :) I usually call this dir "src" for having less things to type. A better name would be something that describes its purpose. For example if it was a RESTful web service you could call that folder `rest`. +1 for my imagination :D

Answer (score 3):

> I really dont want to be stuck with using the project name itself in the import

Why not? It's the best way. Note that 'relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged', - as [said in PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: I want it to be as portable as possible, even when renaming the project. Thats why I see using the project name in the import as a last resort.

Comment: @xeor If you want an app to be portable, you can't rely on project's data. Move `global_stuff` into app's folder or make `global_stuff` another app and add `requirements.txt`.

Comment: A core app is created :) Thanks for the idea